# How to get a react Refs using recompose?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recompose

I need to get a dom reference for a stateless react component during `componentDidMount` using `recompose`. I tried to inspect `this` inside that function bu I cannot get a reference of the dom.

I would like to know how to access the dom for that component.

```
const ComponentX = ({
  classes,
}: Props) => (
  <div>
   Some content
  </div>
)

export const ComponentX = compose<Props, OuterProps>(
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
       // get a reference component dom
    },
  }),
  setDisplayName('ComponentX'),
  injectSheet(styles),
)(ComponentXComp)
```